# NSMutableURLRequest handle special characters in soap request

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, web-services

The request(`NSMutableURLRequest` handle special characters in soap request) is not sent on server when we put logs in server. When i call webservice, server is not getting the reqest which i place it from my device. please help me if you have idea.

Answer (score 1):

All special chars will go in soap request except < > and &. So you need to do some work around for them.

You need to replace them like following at iOS end.

```
-(NSString*)replaceSpecialCharsFromString:(NSString*)str
{
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"];

    return str;
}
```

Now when you receive this response at portal, at that moment you should have code to replace   & to &, < to < , > to > in your store procedure before you insert in portal database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this for making mutableurlrequest safe characters:-

NSString method stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: